# How to write Test class for this below code

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

```java
public List<HistoryTimelineObject> processTimelineItem(id recordId, Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize){
    List<HistoryTimelineObject> wrappedCase = new List<HistoryTimelineObject>();

    List<Case> t = [SELECT Id, Subject, AccountId, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name
    FROM   Case
    WHERE  Applicant__c = :recordId
    LIMIT :pageSize
    OFFSET :pageNo];
    if(t != null){
        for(Integer i = 0, CaseSize = t.size(); i < CaseSize; i++){
            wrappedCase.add(new HistoryTimelineObject().setActor(t[i].CreatedBy.Name)
                    .setHeader(t[i].Subject)
                    .setDate(t[i].CreatedDate.format())
                    .setIconName('standard:case')
                    .setIconColour('put the colour in here'));

        }
    }

    return wrappedCase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Case object and insert in your test class method. Call the above method from test class method. Assure that case value inserted and the data your passing in the parameter to call above method are same.
For further reference for test class,
[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_test.htm]